# find the third vertex coordinates given the other 2 vertices and the angle

Tags: geometry

Please help me finding the formula to find the third vertex (C) coordinates in a triangle given the coordinates of the other 2 vertices (A) and (B) , the angle at B and the length of the edge (a) [image: like in this figure]
Thanks

Comment: wrong forum. is that a homework?

Comment: This question probably belongs in [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Cosine Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_rule) to figure out the length of each edge, and just go from there. You should have an easy time if you have the lengths of all edges. The length of edge c can be found by using sqrt((b.x-a.x)^2+(b.y-a.y)^2).